# it’s safe to run mysqltuner on production server

Tags: mysql, mysqltuner

Can i run mysqltuner directly on a production server ? It’s will slowdown my server or install some packages ? My users will be affected ?

Comment: Please post complete report from your MySQLTuner.pl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most monitoring services have small enough impact that they can (and should) be run on production servers.

- `mysqltuner` -- once in a while.  (Tuning is not something that needs repeating very often.)
- `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS` -- periodically.  (Some services use this to build graphs.)
- Have the slowlog turned on (continually) even with a low, but non-zero, `long_query_time`.  (This is my favorite tool for getting useful clues about performance problems.)
- `performance_schema` (early versions had a noticeable impact)
- But *not* the general log -- This is likely to fill up the disk too fast.  When necessary, use it only briefly.

Here's what I request:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis  It includes

- one-time `SHOW VARIABLES` and `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS`, then run that against about 200 checks.
- one-time slowlog digest (after it has been running at least a day) -- followed by an analysis of the "worst" queries.  This often leads to improving the indexes and/or re-formulating some queries.  It may even lead to architectural changes to get away from problematical design patterns.